# Sum all the even numbers in a array

Tags: c

I have this piece of code that is supposed to sum all the even numbers but it isnt working

```
int n, k = 0, sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  if (s[i] % 2 == 0) {
    k++;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sum += s[i];
    printf("%i ", s[i]);
  }
printf("\n sum of even numbers=%i", sum);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isnt working"? Not compiling, throwing error, wrong output? What's your input, intended output, actual output?

Comment: If you loop `i` to `n` and determine `s[i]` is even -- why are you looping again? (better to guard your initial `for` loop with `{ ... }`)

Comment: if i input 2 4 6 8 i get 80

Comment: Please use an auto formatter on your code so we can read it easily.

Comment: Your [lack of] indentation is scary.

Comment: If it is `2, 4, 6, 8 ...` the sum of all **ODD** numbers would be `0`.

Comment: I MEANT EVEN but either way why would i get 80

Comment: Why not `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { if (s[i] % 2 == 0 ) sum += s[i]; }`?

Comment: Why do you have a nested loop in the first place?

Comment: Please provide some [mre] with a `main`. Also, read some good [C programming](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book, and the documentation of your compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: the answer david gave worked

Comment: Glad to help. Easiest way is to write out the steps needed on 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper before you pick up the keyboard. Helps give you a roadmap to code by. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i, sum = 0;
for (i=0; i < n; i++) //n is the number of elements in the array
{
    if (s[i] % 2 == 0)
        sum = sum + s[i];
}
printf("Sum of the even numbers = %d",sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no need for a nested loop. Just delete the inner for

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).